# How to call API's from a URL in Android

Tags: android

I have a URL to a cfm file that contains the API for a application that I am making a mobile version of.  On my end of the application, I need to supply that file with all of the variables it needs (all of which are URLs).  How would I take take these variables created in my application - all of them currently Strings - and give them to the api.cfm file so it use them as needed?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the CFM file (cold fusion) is on a server.
So I guess the best way is to send by get,post,XML,json or the protocol of your choice, and on the server, find out the values and execute the API.

here is the URL for post
https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html

Hope this helps.